# PHP dentro do Array

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou criando um *loop* onde quero exibir apenas o conteúdo que contém a categoria do *slug* da página. Não estou sabendo que variável colocar dentro do *array* `$args` para fazer com que a *slug* da própria página seja a categoria a ser exibida.

Tenho uma função que me permite utilizar `<?php the_slug(); ?>`, retornando o *slug* da página, mas não estou sabendo como colocar isso dentro no *loop*.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
        $args = array('category_name'=>'<?php the_slug(); ?>', 'showposts'=>4);
        $my_post = get_posts( $args );
        if($my_post) : foreach ($my_post as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
      ?>


        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a></div>

      <?php
        endforeach;
        endif;
      ?>
```

Comment: Não seria apenas `'category_name' => the_slug()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que você esteja usando **isto**:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/278432

Basta usar somente a função `get_the_slug` ao invés de `the_slug`

Troque:

```
$args = array('category_name'=>'<?php the_slug(); ?>', 'showposts'=>4);
```

por:

```
$args = array('category_name' => get_the_slug(), 'showposts'=>4);
```

Claro que tem que ver que função esta usando, já que isto creio que não seja algo nativo do Wordpress.